# How do I search within an array of hashes by hash values in ruby?

Tags: ruby, search, hash, arrays

I have an array of hashes, @fathers.

```
a_father = { "father" => "Bob", "age" =>  40 }
@fathers << a_father
a_father = { "father" => "David", "age" =>  32 }
@fathers << a_father
a_father = { "father" => "Batman", "age" =>  50 }
@fathers << a_father
```

How can I search this array and return an array of hashes for which a block returns true?

For example:

```
@fathers.some_method("age" > 35) #=> array containing the hashes of bob and batman
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question is quite helpful but I couldn't stop wondering why would one need an array of @fathers :P

Comment: @ARK I was slightly preoccupied with that question, but that was completely eclipsed by my realization that each item in the `@fathers` hash has a 'father' key rather than a 'name' key. I wish I could believe that those are the fathers' fathers, but I can't.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You're looking for [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (also called `find_all`):

```
@fathers.select {|father| father["age"] > 35 }
# => [ { "age" => 40, "father" => "Bob" },
#      { "age" => 50, "father" => "Batman" } ]
```

Per the documentation, it "returns an array containing all elements of [the enumerable, in this case `@fathers`] for which block is not false."

Comment: Oh! You were the first one! Deleting my answer and +1.

Comment: As a note, if you wanted only to find a single one (the first one) you can use `@fathers.find {|father| father["age"] > 35 }` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to return the index of where this was found in the original array of hashes?

Comment: @IanWarner Yes. I suggest looking at the docs for the Enumerable module. If you still can't figure it out, post a new question.

Comment: I just did this index  = ARRAY.index { | h | h[ :code ] == ARRAY[ "code" ] }

Comment: what is the fastest way to find it using the unique hash value, with  no condition, the condition is `father["unique_id"] == 35` and not `>` and we use a unique id instead of age ? Any suggestions ? I wan to find out the the father with that id.

Answer (score 223):

this will return first match

```
@fathers.detect {|f| f["age"] > 35 }
```

Comment: I prefer this over `#select` - But all goes for your use case. `#detect` will return `nil` if no match is found, while `#select`, in @Jordan's answer, will return `[]`.

Comment: You could also use `find` instead of `detect` for a more readable code

Comment: `find` can get confusing in rails, however.

Comment: `select` and `detect` aren't same, `select` will transverse the whole array, while `detect` will stop as soon as the first match is found. IF you're looking for ONE match 
`@fathers.select {|f| f["age"] > 35 }.first` vs 
`@fathers.detect {|f| f["age"] > 35 }` 

for performance and readability, my vote goes for `detect`

Answer (score 45):

if your array looks like

```
array = [
 {:name => "Hitesh" , :age => 27 , :place => "xyz"} ,
 {:name => "John" , :age => 26 , :place => "xtz"} ,
 {:name => "Anil" , :age => 26 , :place => "xsz"} 
]
```

And you Want To know if some value is already present in your array. Use Find Method

```
array.find {|x| x[:name] == "Hitesh"}
```

This will return object if Hitesh is present in name otherwise return nil

Comment: If the name was lowercase like `"hitesh"`, it wont return the hash. How can we account for word casing as well in such cases?

Comment: you can use something like.

array.find {|x| x[:name].downcase == "Hitesh".downcase }

Comment: @arjun `array.any?{ |element| element[:name].casecmp("hitesh")==0 }` should work for any case in start or anywhere in the string i.e. for `"Hitesh"`, `"hitesh"` or `"hiTeSh"`

Comment: actually check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63375479/10313894

Comment: `find` is an alias for `detect` method

Answer (score 7):

(Adding to previous answers (hope that helps someone):)

**Age is simpler but in case of string and with ignoring case:**

- Just to verify the presence:

`@fathers.any? { |father| father[:name].casecmp("john") == 0 }` should work for any case in start or anywhere in the string i.e. for `"John"`, `"john"` or `"JoHn"` and so on.

- To find first instance/index:

`@fathers.find { |father| father[:name].casecmp("john") == 0 }`

- To select all such indices:

`@fathers.select { |father| father[:name].casecmp("john") == 0 }`