# ActiveRecord Using .where() on dirty (unsaved) relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have this relationship

models/person.rb

```
class Person
  belongs_to :group
end
```

models/group.rb

```
class Group
  has_many :people
end
```

Now I create a person and assign a new group

```
group = Group.create(name: 'Group A')
group.person.new(name: 'John')
group.person.new(name: 'Lucy')
# Now if I call group.person.where(name: 'Lucy') 
# here it will return an empty result, 
# because it has not been persisted to the database.
```

Is there anyway to include the unsaved records in the search?

My reason for wanting to do this is I need to create a *lot* of people for a group, and need to perform a where() query in the middle to see if I have already added someone with that name. I would rather just call group.save after instantiating all the people as it executes in one transaction rather than an individual transaction for each person which is much slower.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not saving the records to database renders `where` method useless. Only possible solution I can see here is `Array` manipulation.

You can take advantage of ruby's array `select` method here

```
group.persons.new(name: 'John')
group.persons.new(name: 'Lucy')

group.persons.select{|x| x['name']=='Lucy'} # will return the record
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244915/how-do-i-search-within-an-array-of-hashes-by-hash-values-in-ruby) and [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select)

Comment: Update the select block to use ==

Comment: @shiva : But `=` is wrong. It changes the name of the first record and returns the record after that, because the name is not `nil`. Must be `==`

Comment: `=` sets the value of x['name'].  `select` wants a conditional.  Per the docs `Invokes the block passing in successive elements from self, returning an array containing those elements for which the block returns a true value`

Comment: Cool.  Nick will need to combine this checking of the new records with checking of existing records.  I would probably just issue a query for the existing records: `Persons.where(:name, "Lucy").count == 0`