# How to check if an array parameter to a Puppet resource contains a value

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I am writting a custom puppet module which includes an ::apache::vhost resource, and would like to verify in my rspec tests that the directories parameter contains a certain value, without reproducing the entire directories configuration which is mostly hardcoded in the spec test.

```
class foo::apache {

  # prepend 'from ' to each element in array of subnets
  # Change this ugliness to use map once we've upgraded to puppet v4
  # open to suggetions on better way to do this too...
  $subnets = $::foo::subnets
  $subnets_yaml = inline_template('<%= subnets.map {|s| "from " +s}.to_yaml %>')
  $allowed_subnets_directives = parseyaml($subnets_yaml)

  ::apache::vhost { 'foo_vhost':
    directories => [
       -- snip --
        ##### How can I check just the path & allow keys of this element?
      { 'path' => '~^.*$',
        'Order' => 'deny,allow',
        'allow' => concat(['from localhost'],
                   $allowed_subnets_directives),
        'provider' => 'location',
      },
    ]
  } # foo_vhost
} # foo::apache
```

I've removed most of the manifest for brevity.

I can test the entire directives parameter with something along the lines of

```
describe 'foo::apache' do
  it { is_expected.to contain_apache__vhost('foo_vhost').with(
    'directories' => [{'path' => '~^.*$',
                       'allow' => ['from localhost',
                                   'from 10.20.30/24',
                                  ],},
                     ]
```

but the directories parameter is long and static, and I'm keen to avoid that.

The rspec `include` matcher looks like what I need, but I can't work out how to use it to verify the parameter, or the `$allowed_subnets_directives` variable

Comment: FWIW, prepending stuff to everything in an array can be done in older versions using [the regsubst function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#regsubst).

Answer (score 1):

I recently stumbled onto this same problem.  There isn't a clean way to directly access the inner part of a parameter.

I was talking with dev_el_ops in the voxpupuli channel on freenode and he said "one of the design problems of rspec-pupet is that it  doesn't expose property values to the regular rspec matchers"

I'm not sure on the best way to 'find a hash with a key in an array' in ruby, so I'm referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244915/how-do-i-search-within-an-array-of-hashes-by-hash-values-in-ruby)
The way that I would test the above is something like this

```
it do
  vhost_directories = catalogue.resource('apache__vhost', 'foo_vhost').send(:parameters)[:directories]
  expect(vhost_directories.find {|x| x[:path] == '~^.*$'}).to be_truthy
end
```

If you make the assumption that it is in the first entry in the array, you could use a slightly more readable ['include' matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher) on the hash.

```
it do
  vhost_directories = catalogue.resource('apache__vhost', 'foo_vhost').send(:parameters)[:directories]
  expect(vhost_directories.first).to include(:path => '~^.*$')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This request is some what old, however it is still relevant with rspec-puppet and puppet 5+.  At least for simple (top-level) arrays, its possible to use regex values to test whether the value is contained in the parameters.

As an example, for the simple puppet class:

```
# simple test with array parameter
class array_test(
  Array[String] $values = [],
) {
  notify{"And the values are: ${values}": }
}
```

The following test includes regex checks for the expected values:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'spec_helper'
describe 'array_test' do

  context 'with default values for all parameters' do
    it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }
    it { is_expected.to contain_class('array_test') }
  end
  context 'with there parameters' do
    let(:params) {{
      'values' => ['a','b','c','abcd']
    }}

    it { is_expected.to contain_class('array_test').with('values' => %r{"a"}) }
    it { is_expected.to contain_class('array_test').with('values' => %r{"b"}) }
    it { is_expected.to contain_class('array_test').with('values' => %r{"c"}) }
    it { is_expected.to contain_class('array_test').with('values' => %r{"abcd"}) }
    it { is_expected.not_to contain_class('array_test').with('values' => %r{"d"}) }
  end
end
```

Which, when ran, results in the following output:

```
$ bundle exec rake spec
(in /home/vagrant/git/array_test)
I, [2019-08-01T15:35:28.987120 #6373]  INFO -- : Creating symlink from spec/fixtures/modules/array_test to /home/vagrant/git/array_test
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/ruby -I/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib:/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-support-3.8.2/lib /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\{aliases,classes,defines,functions,hosts,integration,plans,tasks,type_aliases,types,unit\}/\*\*/\*_spec.rb

array_test
  with default values for all parameters
    should compile into a catalogue without dependency cycles
    should contain Class[array_test]
  with there parameters
    should contain Class[array_test] with values =~ /"a"/
    should contain Class[array_test] with values =~ /"b"/
    should contain Class[array_test] with values =~ /"c"/
    should contain Class[array_test] with values =~ /"abcd"/
    should not contain Class[array_test] with values =~ /"d"/

Finished in 1.03 seconds (files took 4.26 seconds to load)
7 examples, 0 failures


Code coverage
  must cover at least 0% of resources
Total resources:   2
Touched resources: 0
Resource coverage:  0.00%

Untouched resources:
  Notify[And the values are: []]
  Notify[And the values are: [a, b, c, abcd]]
```