# How do I pull out an object from an array that contains a key with a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is how to I pull out a specific object from this array that has an 'id' with the specific value of 888?

```
[{    "token" => "1212",
   "category" => "A",
       "name" => "page 2",
         "id" => "888"
 },

 {    "token" => "3434",
   "category" => "B",
       "name" => "page 1",
         "id" => "999",
 }]
```

I have tried find_by, where, and a whole host of other things.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244915/how-do-i-search-within-an-array-of-hashes-by-hash-values-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using "select" on the array:

```
arr.select {|k| k['id'] == "888" }
```

This will return an array containing *all* array elements where the condition is met.