# Rails: Query an array based on a record (string) from another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Each User has many `SaleItems` and many `NeededItems`. I want to query User 1's SaleItem names to see if any of them has a similar name to User 2's NeededItems ("name" is the only attribute)

```
@needed_item_of_user2 = NeededItem.where("user_id = ?", 2).first  
# "Pikachu Pokemon card"
@sale_items_of_user1 = SaleItem.where("user_id = ?", 1) 
# "Baseball cards", "Water Heater", "Pikachu doll", "Squirtle Pokemon card"
@matching_sale_items = @sale_items_of_user1.some_method_querying_the_names.@needed_item_of_user2.name 
# It should output either "Squirtle Pokemon card" (high accuracy) or 
# all except "Water Heater" (low accuracy)
```

What method should I use to get an accurate match for `@matching_sale_items?`

I've tried:

```
@matching_sale_items = @sale_items_of_user1.select do |sale| 
  sale["name"] == @needed_item_of_user2.name
end
```

based on [How do I search within an array of hashes by hash values in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244915/how-do-i-search-within-an-array-of-hashes-by-hash-values-in-ruby)

and

```
@matching_sale_items = @sale_items_of_user1.map do |a|
  a.name.downcase
end.grep(/#{@needed_item_of_user2.name.downcase[0,4]}/)  
# outputs strings
```

In the future, I want to use that method to query the SaleItems Table for matches with the NeedItems Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
user1 = User.find 1
user2 = User.find 2
needed_items_names = user2.needed_items.pluck(:name)
matched_items = user1.sale_items.where(name: needed_items_names)
```

Docs to read:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions
  2.3.3 Subset Conditions

Comment: Thanks for pluck. I found this one to search the array for nonexact matches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model

`@matched_items = user1.sale_items.where("LOWER(name) ILIKE ?", "%#{@needed_item_of_user2.name.downcase[0,5]}%")`