# Ruby how to check a values in a nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

I have a nested hash like this where it can have 50 values:

```
{
 "pool1"=>{"name"=>"my-pool", "partition"=>"Common"},
 "pool2"=>{"name"=>"test-2", "partition"=>"baas"}
}
```

I am trying to get all of the pools with the key `"partition"=>"baas"`. like this:

```
 {"pool7"=>{"name"=>"test-7", "partition"=>"baas"}
 {"pool12"=>{"name"=>"test-12", "partition"=>"baas"}
 {"pool18"=>{"name"=>"test-18", "partition"=>"baas"}}
```

This is how i am trying to do this.

```
def test(partition_name,hash)
        a = 1
        b = partition_name
        c = {}
        d = 1

        partition_hash.each do |i|

           f = i.fetch(":pool#{a}",{}.fetch(:partition, false))

            if f = b
                c["pool#{d + 1}"] = i
                d = d +1
            end
            a = a +1
        end
end
```

I now get an error like this:

`[no implicit conversion of String into Integer]`

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244915/how-do-i-search-within-an-array-of-hashes-by-hash-values-in-ruby this question can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just `select` for that:

```
p hash.select { |_, value| value['partition'] == 'baas' }
```